# @ControllerAdvice does not catch MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: spring-boot, controller-advice

I am making a Spring Boot app with MySQL database attached to it.

I have already marked **username** as unique in the user-table, and the DB throws a **MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException** when i try to add a new user with an existing username.

Is there a way to make the ControllerAdvice handle this exception ? I tried making the handler like this :

```
@ExceptionHandler(MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    @ResponseBody
    public MyBadInputResponse databaseIntegrityViolationDuplicate(MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ex) {
        MyBadInputResponse bir = new MyBadInputResponse("The request value already exists in the database", 
                ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        logger.error(bir.toString());
        return bir;
    }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you annotating your bean (that contains the `ExceptionHandler` method) with a `@ControllerAdvice` ?

Comment: Of course. And all the other ExceptionHandlers in that controller advice are working.

Comment: Generally those specific exceptions are converted to Spring `DataAccessException` subclasses. So your code will never throw a `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` but rather a `DataIntegrityViolationException` from Spring.

Comment: That seems to work. Thanks. :)